# Binding of Zebra SDK to Monotouch?

Tags: binding, sdk, xamarin.ios, zebra-printers

I'm working on an iPad app in Monotouch (5.2.12). The app will be used with Zebra's mobile printers, so we got SDK from them (.a library and headers). So I went to read all the guides and tutorials and created a bindings project for it (just 2 connection classes). I was really excited to get it working quickly for basic text and label printing.

But we'll need to print PDFs. To do that, I need to bind more classes and I just cannot figure out how for 2 days now. Here's the general setup of the library:

ZebraPrinterConnection protocol is implemented by TcpPrinterConnection interface.
ZebraPrinterFactory interface is used to obtain an instance of ZebraPrinter protocol and requires ZebraPrinterConnection to be passed to it.

Here's the core of the bindings:

### **ZebraPrinterConnection**

*Header (.h)*

```
@protocol ZebraPrinterConnection        
    - (BOOL) open;
    - (void) close;
    - (NSInteger) write:(NSData *)data error:(NSError **)error;
    - (NSData *)read: (NSError**)error;
```

*Binding (.cs)*

```
[BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
[Model]
    interface ZebraPrinterConnection {
        [Export ("open")]
        bool Open();

         [Export ("close")]
         void Close();

         [Export ("write:error:")]
         int Write(NSData data, out NSError error);

         [Export ("read:")]
         NSData Read(out NSError error);
    }
```

### **TcpPrinterConnection**

*Header (.h)*

```
@interface TcpPrinterConnection : NSObject<ZebraPrinterConnection>
  - (id)initWithAddress:(NSString *)anAddress andWithPort:(NSInteger)aPort;
```

*Binding (.cs)*

```
[BaseType (typeof(ZebraPrinterConnection))]
interface TcpPrinterConnection {        
    [Export ("initWithAddress:andWithPort:")]
    IntPtr Constructor (string anAddress, int aPort);
}
```

### **ZebraPrinterFactory**

*Header (.h)*

```
@interface ZebraPrinterFactory : NSObject
  +(id<ZebraPrinter,NSObject>) getInstance:(id<ZebraPrinterConnection, NSObject>) 
    connection error:(NSError**)error
```

*Binding (.cs)*

```
[BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]
interface ZebraPrinterFactory {
  [Static, Export ("getInstance:error:")]
  ZebraPrinter getInstance(ZebraPrinterConnection connection, out NSError error);
}
```

### The problem:

Note how ZebraPrinterFactory wants `ZebraPrinterConnection` to be passed to it, but only `TcpPrinterConnection` has an actual constructor.

If I try to use something like:

```
NSError err;
TcpPrinterConnection conn;
conn = new TcpPrinterConnection(ipAddress, port);
bool connectionOK = conn.Open ();
ZebraPrinter zPrinter = ZebraPrinterFactory.getInstance(conn, out err);
```

then I get a "System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type." at runtime...

It's a terrible feeling knowing that you ALMOST got it working, but not quite... How does one get around this?

**UPDATE:** OK, I removed the ZebraPrinterConnection class from the binding entirely, copying its methods into TcpPrinterConnection (as suggested by Jonathan). Still no luck (same exception). Then bound another class that has methods that expect ZebraPrinterConnection as a parameter and this one works smooth as silk.

*Header (.h)*

```
@interface SGD : NSObject {}
  +(NSString*) GET: (NSString*) setting 
    withPrinterConnection: (id<ZebraPrinterConnection,NSObject>) printerConnection 
    error:(NSError**)error;
```

*Binding (.cs)*

```
[BaseType (typeof (NSObject))]
interface SGD 
{
  [Static, Export ("GET:withPrinterConnection:error:")]
  string Get (string setting, TcpPrinterConnection printerConnection, out NSError error);
}
```

I am starting to suspect the implementation of ZebraPrinterFactory class being root of the problem, now that other classes can be bound without any issues whatsoever. On the other hand, it might have something to do with the returned instance of ZebraPrinter class. Could it be that Mono cannot map ZebraPrinter to the thing being returned by the factory class?

Comment: I can confirm that this type of approach worked for me.  I am working on a MonoTouch binding for the open source ObjectAL project.  Part of the OALSimpleAudio class includes playEffect methods that return id<ALSoundSource>.  ALSoundSource is an Objective-C protocol.  It wasn't until I changed method references to ALSource, a class that implements ALSoundSource and is ultimately returned by playEffect, that I was able to get things to work.  Previously, I encountered System.InvalidCastException when trying to use the playEffect method.

Comment: I'm working on the same problem, any chance you'd share the bindings? It will help me a great deal

Comment: I would also like to see the bindings you have, I'm having problem creating the binding for the ZebraPrinter interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with MonoTouch, but know about the zebra apis. Hopefully some background of the way the sdk works will help with these mono mappings

So, the ZebraPrinterFactory is a simple factory which interrogates a printer connection to figure out which model of printer you have (ZPL or CPCL). The return type of the factory is an Interface, `ZebraPrinter`.  The concrete type of a `ZebraPrinter` is an internal, non documented class, `ZebraPrinterZpl` or `ZebraPrinterCpcl`.  Both of these concrete classes conform to the `ZebraPrinter` interface and can perform functions on a printer. We chose to do this to abstract away the need to know about printer languages.  But if Mono needs to know about a concrete class to perform the mapping, you can cast the return to the concrete class `ZebraPrinterCpcl` or `ZebraPrinterZpl` (depending on your printer model, small mobile printers are probably cpcl, large desktops or tabletops are ZPL)

You can alternatively bypass the factory by instatiating a concrete type of printer by just calling its constructor (unfortunately, it is not documented, because the factory is the preferred way to do this)  But it would be something like this:

```
ZebraPrinterCpcl myPrinter = new ZebraPrinterCpcl(conn);  
//or using the base interface as the type... and you may need to pass in an NSError also, I forget now...
ZebraPrinter myPrinter = new ZebraPrinterCpcl(conn);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It did help! OTisler, you are awesome! I did find someone mentioning ZebraPrinterCpcl classes for Android SDK on Zebra support forums, but I didn't realize it could help me as well. Another thing is that, of course, Monotouch refused to perform `zPrinter.getGraphicsUtil()` with the same exception. I assumed that there are concrete classes implementing GraphicsUtil protocol and applied the same logic, binding `GraphicsUtilCpcl` class. And it worked! Thanks you so much!

Comment: sweet! Just fyi, you are now calling private, non documented API which can change at any time. Not really recommended, but if it works, better than not working, eh? I'll have to look at this Mono thing when I get a chance, I've never heard of it, but if it's popular, we should try to support it in our API

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
[BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]
interface TcpPrinterConnection : ZebraPrinterConnection {
```

Use:

```
[BaseType (typeof(ZebraPrinterConnection ))]
interface TcpPrinterConnection {
```

Then the binding project should setup your inheritance correctly.  The `BaseType` attribute determines the base class, not actually inheriting the interface (I know it's a little weird).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will try that tomorrow (it's 10 p.m. here and I had given up several hours ago). If I recall correctly, I tried something similar and ended up with the same runtime exception.

Comment: Unfortunately, Jonathan, your answer above didn't help. I updated the bindings, had to remove [Model] attribute from the base class, otherwise it gave me "You_Should_Not_Call_Base_In_This_Method" exception on TcpPrinterConnection.Open() . After that it gives me runtime exception "System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type." when I try to use factory class. Furthermore, inspecting the instance of TcpPrinterConnection in the debugger immediately crashes the app.

Comment: Inspection crash resolved, had to do with binding private properties of TcpPrinterConnection class. Still, the invalid cast exception is there. Does it mean that MonoTouch runtime cannot convert one type to the other despite the first being derived from the second?..

Comment: You definitely don't need to use the `Model` attribute.  Have you tried removing the base interface entirely?  Just make a binding for `TcpConnection` and place all the methods from the base class in there as well.  This should work because of the way Obj-C message passing works.

Comment: Just removed the base ZebraPrinterConnection class from the binding, copying all of its methods into TcpPrinterConnection. Same invalid cast exception. Funny thing is, I bound another class that expects to get ZebraPrinterConnection as a parameter and it works... `(NSString*) GET: (NSString*) setting withPrinterConnection:(id<ZebraPrinterConnection,NSObject>) printerConnection 
error:(NSError**)error` bound as `[Static, Export("SET:withValue:andWithPrinterConnection:error:")]
  bool Set (string setting, string value, TcpPrinterConnection printerConnection, out NSError error);`

Comment: Now I'm suspecting that something is wrong with the headers or the implementation of ZebraPrinterFactory class.

Comment: Try changing the parameter that takes a `TcpPrinterConnection`, and change it to an `IntPtr`, then send your connections `Handle` property through.  It is a longshot, but I wonder what will happen there.